# Why does using await in different places in my async function gives different results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, async-await, sequelize.js

This is perhaps the strangest thing that ever happened to me ever since I started coding:

> Scenario 1: Await is used in the beginning of the function

```
const resObj = operationsSav.map(async operationSav => {
    Asyncproduit = await operationSav.getProduit();
    logger.error(
      "retrieved produit by using Async is",
      Asyncproduit.nom_produit
    );

    const mapStatusToDisplayedValue = {
      produit_recu: "Produit reçu",
      en_livraison: "En livraison",
      en_reparation: "En cours de réparation",
      repare: "Réparé",
      en_expedition: "Envoyé au client",
      expedie: "Reçu par le client",
      annule: "Annulé"
    };


    return Object.assign({
      id: operationSav.id,
      nom_operation: operationSav.nom_operation,
      num_serie: operationSav.num_serie,
      address_mac: operationSav.address_mac,
      sous_garantie: operationSav.sous_garantie,
      description: operationSav.description,
      admin: admin.nom,
      produitNom: Asyncproduit.nom_produit,
      status: mapStatusToDisplayedValue[operationSav.status],
      nomClient: operationSav.nomClient
    });
  });
  const operationSavToDisplay = await Promise.all(resObj);
```

In thise scenario: the retrieved `Asyncproduit` is always the same as you may see in the log result:

```
2020-03-04T09:36:40+0100 <error> OperationSavServices.js:121  retrieved produit by using Async is + PLAYER BLACK MAT FILAIRE
2020-03-04T09:36:40+0100 <error> OperationSavServices.js:121  retrieved produit by using Async is + PLAYER BLACK MAT FILAIRE
2020-03-04T09:36:40+0100 <error> OperationSavServices.js:121  retrieved produit by using Async is + PLAYER BLACK MAT FILAIRE
2020-03-04T09:36:40+0100 <error> OperationSavServices.js:121  retrieved produit by using Async is + PLAYER BLACK MAT FILAIRE
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "nom", "email", "mot_de_passe", "last_login", "role", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "admins" AS "admin" WHERE "admin"."id" = 75;
2020-03-04T09:36:40+0100 <error> OperationSavServices.js:121  retrieved produit by using Async is + PLAYER BLACK MAT FILAIRE
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "nom", "email", "mot_de_passe", "last_login", "role", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "admins" AS "admin" WHERE "admin"."id" = 75;
2020-03-04T09:36:40+0100 <error> OperationSavServices.js:121  retrieved produit by using Async is + PLAYER BLACK MAT FILAIRE
2020-03-04T09:36:40+0100 <error> OperationSavServices.js:121  retrieved produit by using Async is + PLAYER BLACK MAT FILAIRE
2020-03-04T09:36:40+0100 <error> OperationSavServices.js:121  retrieved produit by using Async is + PLAYER BLACK MAT FILAIRE
2020-03-04T09:36:40+0100 <error> OperationSavServices.js:121  retrieved produit by using Async is + PLAYER BLACK MAT FILAIRE
2020-03-04T09:36:40+0100 <error> OperationSavServices.js:121  retrieved produit by using Async is + PLAYER BLACK MAT FILAIRE
2020-03-04T09:36:40+0100 <error> OperationSavServices.js:121  retrieved produit by using Async is + PLAYER BLACK MAT FILAIRE
```

> Scenario 2: Await is used in the middle of the function

```
 const resObj = operationsSav.map(async operationSav => {

    const mapStatusToDisplayedValue = {
      produit_recu: "Produit reçu",
      en_livraison: "En livraison",
      en_reparation: "En cours de réparation",
      repare: "Réparé",
      en_expedition: "Envoyé au client",
      expedie: "Reçu par le client",
      annule: "Annulé"
    };

    /** TESTING GET PRODUIT WITH ASYNC AWAIT */
    Asyncproduit = await operationSav.getProduit();
    logger.error(
      "retrieved produit by using Async is",
      Asyncproduit.nom_produit
    );

    /** TESTING GET PRODUIT WITH ASYNC AWAIT */
    return Object.assign({
      id: operationSav.id,
      nom_operation: operationSav.nom_operation,
      num_serie: operationSav.num_serie,
      address_mac: operationSav.address_mac,
      sous_garantie: operationSav.sous_garantie,
      description: operationSav.description,
      admin: admin.nom,
      produitNom: Asyncproduit.nom_produit,
      status: mapStatusToDisplayedValue[operationSav.status],
      nomClient: operationSav.nomClient
    });
  });
  const operationSavToDisplay = await Promise.all(resObj);
```

In thise scenario: the retrieved `Asyncproduit` is different as you may see in the log result:

```
2020-03-04T09:43:02+0100 <error> OperationSavServices.js:93  retrieved produit by using Async is + PURE LIMITED CHROME GOLD MEMORY 256G
2020-03-04T09:43:02+0100 <error> OperationSavServices.js:93  retrieved produit by using Async is + PURE PLUS BLACK MAT MEMORY 128 G
2020-03-04T09:43:02+0100 <error> OperationSavServices.js:93  retrieved produit by using Async is + PURE PLUS BLACK MAT MEMORY 128 G
2020-03-04T09:43:02+0100 <error> OperationSavServices.js:93  retrieved produit by using Async is + PURE LIMITED CHROME GOLD MEMORY 256G
2020-03-04T09:43:02+0100 <error> OperationSavServices.js:93  retrieved produit by using Async is + GAME ONE WHITE
2020-03-04T09:43:02+0100 <error> OperationSavServices.js:93  retrieved produit by using Async is + PLAYER BLACK MAT FILAIRE
2020-03-04T09:43:02+0100 <error> OperationSavServices.js:93  retrieved produit by using Async is + PLAYER GOLD MAT FILAIRE
2020-03-04T09:43:02+0100 <error> OperationSavServices.js:93  retrieved produit by using Async is + GAME ONE WHITE
```

The results in **Scenario 2** are the **correct results**. The association between `operationsSav` and `produit` is defined as follows:

```
  /** produit Has Many operation_sav*/
  model.operation_sav.belongsTo(model.produit, {
    foreignKeyConstraint: true,
    onDelete: "cascade"
  });

  model.produit.hasMany(model.operation_sav, {
    foreignKeyConstraint: true,
    onDelete: "cascade"
  });
```

Which means that every row in the `operation_sav` table is associated with a row in the `produit` table. **But**, this doesn't mean the `produit` is always the same. Each `operation_sav`row can be associated with a different `produit` which is the case in my database as **Scenario 2** proves.
I was baffled why the database was returning the same `produit` in scenario one, and I have solved this with sheer luck.
**Now**, I'd like to understand why is the code behaving differently in the two scenarios!

**EDIT 1** This is the whole code. Notice the first lines:

```
 const resObj = operationsSav.map(async operationSav => {
    // This line wasn't written in the code above, maybe it was causing the problem?
    admin = await operationSav.getAdmin();
    /** TESTING GET PRODUIT WITH ASYNC AWAIT */
    Asyncproduit = await operationSav.getProduit();
    logger.error(
      "retrieved produit by using Async is",
      Asyncproduit.nom_produit
    );

    /** TESTING GET PRODUIT WITH ASYNC AWAIT */
    const mapStatusToDisplayedValue = {
      produit_recu: "Produit reçu",
      en_livraison: "En livraison",
      en_reparation: "En cours de réparation",
      repare: "Réparé",
      en_expedition: "Envoyé au client",
      expedie: "Reçu par le client",
      annule: "Annulé"
    };

    return Object.assign({
      id: operationSav.id,
      nom_operation: operationSav.nom_operation,
      num_serie: operationSav.num_serie,
      address_mac: operationSav.address_mac,
      sous_garantie: operationSav.sous_garantie,
      description: operationSav.description,
      admin: admin.nom,
      produitNom: Asyncproduit.nom_produit,
      status: mapStatusToDisplayedValue[operationSav.status],
      nomClient: operationSav.nomClient
    });
  });
  const operationSavToDisplay = await Promise.all(resObj);
```

Comment: The obvious mistake is that `Asyncproduit` is an undeclared global variable. Use strict mode to make it error, and use `const` to make it local.

Comment: With apologies, I don't believe the code given above behaves as described. I think you must have removed something that didn't seem relevant. Changing the location of that first `await` makes more of the beginning of the function run synchronously, but since the only code prior to it in "Scenario 2" is creating a local variable and assigning an object to it that doesn't use anything from outside the function, moving the `await` as above won't change anything.

Comment: But it's weird indeed that these two codes would have different results. Is that the exact actual code, or are there more `await`s?

Comment: Just to save others the trouble, before posting my comment above I copied the code blocks and compared them. If you remove the comments from "Scenario 2" and move the first five lines of "Scenario 1" to where they are in "Scenario 2," the code is identical. (No other, non-obvious differences.)

Comment: @Bergi There's another await indeed . That does the same thing but retrieves values from a different table. But, what does it have to do with the 'produit' await?

Comment: @AhmedGhrib - Timing. As I said above, the position of the first `await` in an `async` function determines how much of it runs synchronously. Also, if you have other code outside that function that runs after the `Asyncproduit = ...` in Scenario 1 but before it in Scenario 2, does that code use `Asyncproduit` (which isn't local to the function above)? Etc. etc. I'm afraid this is a case of you'll have to track it down with debugging, it's not likely something we can help you with (other than these comments). Good luck! I hope you find it sooner rather than later. :-)

Comment: @Bergi checkout the edit,  I have added the removed code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Asyncproduit is only used in Object.assign . I am surprised with your phrase ' the position of the first await in an async function determines how much of it runs synchronously.'. So the position of await does matter. I think I need to learn more about how the asynchronous code functions in order to solve this.

Comment: @AhmedGhrib - Yes, that surprises a lot of people. An `async` function runs synchronously up to the first `await` or `return`, at which point it returns a promise. That's so it can start things it may wait for. In the case of `await`, the function's execution continues later when the promise it was awaiting settles. (If `Asyncproduit` is only used in that function, declare it locally. RIght now that code is running into what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okay, thank you so much for the clarifications :) I will make sure to read that

Comment: (FWIW, I go into promises and `async` functions in some detail in Chapters 8 and 9 of my new book out in a couple of months, see my profile for details.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder okay will do :)